# How do you put onDestroy in a recyclerview adapter? Is it possible?

Tags: android

I'm making this app with text to speech in the adapter but whenever I close the app, the text to speech continues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it yourself.

In your adapter:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    tts.shutdown();
}
```

In your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    adapter.onDestroy();
}
```

Obviously, you'll have to rename the variables to match what you have.

Comment: You missed the   super.onDestroy(); after adapter.onDestroy(). But thanks though it worked!